# How to do visible EditText Data on Activity change

Tags: android

HellO friends i am having edit text in my program and if i am writing some thing on there and if i am clciking on other option which will move to anothe activity and when i am coming back to same page the data of my edit text is clearing i dont want to clear data if i move on another page can any body tell me how to do it ..i am doing it by writing below code..

```
    if(PresetQuestion.value=="true")
    {
        String note1=note.getText().toString(); 
        note.setText(note1);
              }
```

but its not woring i thing i am not doing correctly ...

Answer (score 1):

use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState)`:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        EditText edttext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textone);

        outState.putString("textone", edttext.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {

        String strval=outState.getString("textone");
        EditText bddb=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textone);
        bddb.setText("prvvalue");
        ///outState.putString(""+idtext+"", bddb.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On moving to another activity, if you want your edit text shows previous, entered data then you should not `finish()` your activity when going to another.
    If you have a this type of requirement to `finish()` the previous activity then use should save the date in Shared Preference such as below:

```
//decleration
SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
//onCreate
  sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
  ed = sp.edit();
String edittextvalue=sp.getString("edtvalue", "");
if(!edittextvalue.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
  {
  edittext.setext(edittextvalue);
  }
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    String editvalue=edittext.getEditableText().toString();
    ed.putString("edtvalue", edtitvalue);
    ed.putInt("check", 1);
    ed.commit();
//start New Activity
  } 
 });
```

Comment: first parameter is preference name & other one is its default value

Comment: and what value i need to pass there ??